# Pandas Dataframe: shift/merge multiple rows sharing the same column values into one row

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for any possible confusion with the title. I will describe my question better with the following code and pictures.

Now I have a dataframe with multiple columns. The first two columns, by which they are sorted, 'Route' and 'ID' (Sorry about the formatting, all the rows here have 'Route' value of '100' and 'ID' from 1 to 3.

```
df1.head(9)
  Route ID  Year    Vol Truck_Vol   Truck_%
0   100 1   2017.0  7016    635.0   9.1
1   100 1   2014.0  6835    NaN NaN
2   100 1   2011.0  5959    352.0   5.9
3   100 2   2018.0  15828   NaN NaN
4   100 2   2015.0  13114   2964.0  22.6
5   100 2   2009.0  11844   1280.0  10.8
6   100 3   2016.0  15434   NaN NaN
7   100 3   2013.0  18699   2015.0  10.8
8   100 3   2010.0  15903   NaN NaN
```

What I want to have is

```
 Route  ID  Year    Vol1    Truck_Vol1  Truck_%1    Year2   Vol2    Truck_Vol2  Truck_%2    Year3   Vol3    Truck_Vol3  Truck_%3
0   100 1   2017    7016    635.0   9.1 2014    6835    NaN NaN 2011    5959    352.0   5.9
1   100 2   2018    15828   NaN NaN 2015    13114   2964.0  22.6    2009    11844   1280.0  10.8
2   100 3   2016    15434   NaN NaN 2013    18699   2015.0  10.8    2010    15903   NaN NaN
```

Again, sorry for the messy formatting. Let me try a simplified version.

Input:

```
  Route ID  Year    Vol T_%
0   100 1   2017    100 1.0
1   100 1   2014    200 NaN
2   100 1   2011    300 2.0
3   100 2   2018    400 NaN
4   100 2   2015    500 3.0
5   100 2   2009    600 4.0
```

Desired Output:

```
Route   ID  Year    Vol T_% Year.1  Vol.1   T_%.1   Year.2  Vol.2   T_%.2
0   100 1   2017    100 1.0 2014    200     NaN     2011    300      2
1   100 2   2018    400 NaN 2015    500     3.0     2009    600      4
```

So basically just move the cells shown in the picture

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

I am stumped here. The names for the newly generated columns don't matter.

For this current dataframe, I have three rows per 'group' like shown in the code. It will be great if the answer can accommodate any number of rows each group.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with `groupby` + `cumcount` + `set_index` + `unstack`

```
df1 = df.assign(cid = df.groupby(['Route', 'ID']).cumcount()).set_index(['Route', 'ID', 'cid']).unstack(-1).sort_index(1,1)
df1.columns = [f'{x}{y}' for x,y in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

#### Output `df1`:

```
   Route  ID  T_%0  Vol0  Year0  T_%1  Vol1  Year1  T_%2  Vol2  Year2
0    100   1   1.0   100   2017   NaN   200   2014   2.0   300   2011
1    100   2   NaN   400   2018   3.0   500   2015   4.0   600   2009
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. This is amazing. But as I never used cumcount and unstack, would you mind explaining a little bit what each step does please? And did the code `[f'{x}{y}' for x,y in df1.columns]` add the `0, 1, 2` at the end of each column name? Thanks again!

Comment: @BowenLiu Sorry for not responding earlier. It seems that @user3483203 explained the reason for cumcount. Because of unstack, I'm left with a MultiIndex for my columns, the first level being the original column name, and the second level being the number from `cumcount`.  `[f'{x}{y}' for x,y in df1.columns]` removes the MultiIndex on the columns and just adds the cumcount value to each of the variable names.

Comment: No worries. I'm more than grateful for your help. Haha, right now tbh I can barely understand your comment. I guess the best way for me to understand it is to play with it bit by bit. I will let you know if I still have any question after playing with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @BowenLiu Okay, then just look at the output of `df1` after each line of code above. I think seeing the difference after the first and second line should show you how that is manipulating the column names. It basically changes it from having two levels `array([('T_%', 0), ('Vol', 0), ...])` to a list with just one level `['T_%0', 'Vol0', ...]`

Comment: Wow, after playing around I realized how helpful the `pyformat` step is. There is only one piece in this whole process that I don't understand now: why does `sort_index(1, 1)` work like it does here? The first `1` means axis is 1 which I understand since we try to sort along the rows from left to right. The second `1` confused me: `level = 1` and at this step that is the `[1, 2]` with name `ID`. Does `sort_index` sort all levels of column names? Thanks!

Comment: @BowenLiu, Yes, the `.sort_index(1,1)` is equivalent to `.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)`. Specifying `axis=1` indicates that I want to sort the columns and by specifying `level=1` I am indicating that I want to sort the columns based only on the values in that level (which is the cumcount variable). Before the sort the 1st level has values [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2] so sorting on that level just makes it [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]. This does not change anything in the output `DataFrame` other than the order in which the columns appear.

Comment: With indices it can be difficult to see directly what the values are, so if you do `df1.columns.get_level_values(1)` after the first line of code you can see exactly what the values for that level are for each column

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. `get_level_values` is a great function. Thanks for letting know that it exists. And it seems like when I `sort_index(level = 1)`, the columns at `level = 0` are also sorted. Did I get it right?

Comment: @BowenLiu yes, it first sorts on the `level=1` values and then sorts the remaining values (`level=0`). You can turn off that feature by adding the argument `sort_remaining=False` to `.sort_index`

Comment: Can't imagine a better answer and explanation process. Really appreciate all your help. I understand it fully now. Also makes me realize how much more I need to know about Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

#### `melt` + `pivot_table`

```
v = df.melt(id_vars=['Route', 'ID'])
v['variable'] += v.groupby(['Route', 'ID', 'variable']).cumcount().astype(str)

res = v.pivot_table(index=['Route', 'ID'], columns='variable', values='value')
```

```
variable  T_% 0  T_% 1  T_% 2  Vol 0  Vol 1  Vol 2  Year 0  Year 1  Year 2
Route ID
100   1     1.0    NaN    2.0  100.0  200.0  300.0  2017.0  2014.0  2011.0
      2     NaN    3.0    4.0  400.0  500.0  600.0  2018.0  2015.0  2009.0
```

If you want to sort these:

```
c = res.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0].values.astype(int)
res.iloc[:,np.argsort(c)]
```

```
variable  T_%0   Vol0   Year0  T_%1   Vol1   Year1  T_%2   Vol2   Year2
Route ID
100   1    1.0  100.0  2017.0   NaN  200.0  2014.0   2.0  300.0  2011.0
      2    NaN  400.0  2018.0   3.0  500.0  2015.0   4.0  600.0  2009.0
```

---

You asked about why I used `cumcount`.  To explain, here is what `v` looks like from above:

```
    Route  ID variable   value
0     100   1     Year  2017.0
1     100   1     Year  2014.0
2     100   1     Year  2011.0
3     100   2     Year  2018.0
4     100   2     Year  2015.0
5     100   2     Year  2009.0
6     100   1      Vol   100.0
7     100   1      Vol   200.0
8     100   1      Vol   300.0
9     100   2      Vol   400.0
10    100   2      Vol   500.0
11    100   2      Vol   600.0
12    100   1      T_%     1.0
13    100   1      T_%     NaN
14    100   1      T_%     2.0
15    100   2      T_%     NaN
16    100   2      T_%     3.0
17    100   2      T_%     4.0
```

If I used `pivot_table` on this DataFrame, you would end up with something like this:

```
variable  T_%    Vol    Year
Route ID
100   1   1.5  200.0  2014.0
      2   3.5  500.0  2014.0
```

---

Obviously you are losing data here.  `cumcount` is the solution, as it turns the `variable` series into this:

```
    Route  ID variable   value
0     100   1    Year0  2017.0
1     100   1    Year1  2014.0
2     100   1    Year2  2011.0
3     100   2    Year0  2018.0
4     100   2    Year1  2015.0
5     100   2    Year2  2009.0
6     100   1     Vol0   100.0
7     100   1     Vol1   200.0
8     100   1     Vol2   300.0
9     100   2     Vol0   400.0
10    100   2     Vol1   500.0
11    100   2     Vol2   600.0
12    100   1     T_%0     1.0
13    100   1     T_%1     NaN
14    100   1     T_%2     2.0
15    100   2     T_%0     NaN
16    100   2     T_%1     3.0
17    100   2     T_%2     4.0
```

Where you have a count of repeated elements per unique `Route` and `ID`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never actually used `df.melt` before as I was confused by what it does. Both you and @ALollz used `cumcount`, would you care to elaborate what it does please? And thanks for the finishing touch of sorting.

Comment: @BowenLiu I added an explanation

Comment: I will start perusing it right now. Thanks a lot. And is there any other way to sort the data than using regex? I asked because when I applied your code to sort the original columns, something very wonky came out. I don't know much about regex haha but I do feel like I really need to learn it.